# Where are emoji-codes like ":smile:" defined?

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding, standards, emoji

I came across the site https://github.com/WebpageFX/emoji-cheat-sheet.com following a tutorial on the library [streamlit](https://streamlit.io/) and it seems to have emoji-codes that are valid for a number of other platforms. From what I understand, the syntax like ":smile:" is not unicode though. Is it just a convention that converged naturally, or is there any standard specifying it?

Comment: You need to provide much more focused information on where and how _:smile:_ is being used. Just giving a couple of links to the home page of a company's web site and a GitHub page is not helpful.

Comment: Based on the inconsistencies I see on this page, I'd have to conclude there is **no** master list.  https://emojibase.dev/shortcodes/?

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks, that answers it. Also nice resource to know :grin: